# How to refer to previous row in data table (R) without using shift function?

Tags: r, loops, datatable, time-series

I am trying to use data table to make my massive modeling work easier. 
I ran into this problem but have not figured out a better way to solve it.

Here's my example:

```
set.seed(1001)
dt1<-data.table("Country"=c("Algeria","Mongolia"),
                "Year"=c(2000:2020),
                "var1"=runif(20,10000,45000),
                "var2"=0,
                "var3"=0,
                "var4"=0)

setorder(dt1,Country)
```

I would like to update var2 by using previous row's values in a specific period
so I tried

```
dt1[Year>2000&Year<2010,var2:=var1[i]-sum(.SD)[i-1],by=Country,.SDcols=c(var2,var3,var4)]
```

Obviously this did not work. The problem is var 2 and the sum of other variables in previous row need to be updated simultaneously. So I don't think shift function would do the work.

For now, I am using very cumbersome for loop for this but it works.Here is my forloop

```
for(i in 1:nrow(dt1)){
  if (i <=10){
    for (j in 4:6){
      if(j==4){
        dt1[[i,j]]=dt1[[i,3]]-rowSums(dt1[[i-1,c(4:6)]])
      }
      else{
        dt1[[i,j]]=dt1[[i-1,j-1]] * 0.001
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestion will be much appreciated!

Comment: In your examples var3, and var4 are 0 are not getting updated.  Not sure why you are summing the 0 values again.  I understand that var2 is getting updated

Comment: If you can update. your post with the expected output, it would be great.  Also, please make sure to use `set.seed` as you are using `runif`

Comment: Hi @akrun, thank you for the reminder! I attached what I am using for now that works but would love to change.